# Angular2/Nativescript: Issues converting a service that used to use LocalStorage to one that uses nativescript-application/settings

Tags: angular, angular2-nativescript

I am busy with a simple barcode scanner app and trying to convert a service which used LocalStorage in a web app before to use application-settings to save a local IP.  The app builds fine but when it gets deployed to a genymotion emulator I get the following error. Any idea why this might be happening?
So it seems like the issue is with the getString and/or setString methods of application-settings.  I coppyed a service from a web app which used LocalStorage and replaced localStorage with appSettings and getItem with getString and setString...  Am i missing something in Nativescript's getString and setString?  I thought it works the exact same way as the LocalStorage browser API...

my error:

```
JS: EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
JS: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
JS: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
JS:     at Object.parse (native)
JS:     at AppSettingsService.findLocalIP (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/services/app-settings.service.js:19:25)
JS:     at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/app.component.js:13:42)
JS:     at Wrapper_AppComponent.detectChangesInInputProps (/AppModule/AppComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:18:53)
JS:     at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:30:26)
JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
JS:     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:48)
JS:     at ViewRef_.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7398:24)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6819:88
JS:     at Array.forEach (native)
JS: ERROR CONTEXT:
JS: [object Object]
JS: ns-renderer: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
JS: ns-renderer: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent_Host - inline template:0:0 caused by: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
JS:
JS: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
JS:     at Object.parse (native)
JS:     at AppSettingsService.findLocalIP (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/services/app-settings.service.js:19:25)
JS:     at AppComponent.ngOnInit (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/app.component.js:13:42)
JS:     at Wrapper_AppComponent.detectChangesInInputProps (/AppModule/AppComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:18:53)
JS:     at DebugAppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:30:26)
JS:     at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9305:18)
JS:     at DebugAppView.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9410:48)
JS:     at ViewRef_.detectChanges (/data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:7398:24)
JS:     at /data/data/org.nativescript.barcodescanner/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:6819:88
JS:     at Array.forEach (native)
8:46:00 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
```

my app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';
import { AppSettingsService } from './services/app-settings.service';


@Component({
    selector: "main",
    template : "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private restService: RestService, private appSettingsService: AppSettingsService, private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let ip = this.appSettingsService.findLocalIP();
           if (ip !== null) {
               this.restService.init(ip);
           } else if (ip === null) {
               this.routerExtensions.navigate(['settings']);
        }
}
```

my app-settings.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as appSettings from 'application-settings';

@Injectable()
export class AppSettingsService {

saveLocalIP(ip: string): void {
  let localData = appSettings.getString('retail_mobile');
  if (localData) {
    localData = JSON.parse(localData);
  } else {
    localData = "";
 }
let saveData = {localIP:ip};
appSettings.setString('retail_mobile', JSON.stringify(saveData));   
}

findLocalIP() {
   let data = JSON.parse(appSettings.getString('retail_mobile'));
   if (data === null) {     
    console.log("No entry found in local storage...");
    return null;
   }

if(data && !data.localIP) {
    console.log("no local ip found in localStorage...")
    return null;
}

return data.localIP;
}

constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` refers to malformed json. And it seems to be connected to `findLocalIP`. I'd start investigating there.

Comment: @AJT_82 the strange thing is I haven't set any ip yet.  In my AppSettingsService I have checks for when the IP hasn't been set so not sure where it could be getting this U from...

Comment: Well now the answer is edited, now it should work, it's not pretty, but should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ngOnInit` is calling the method `findLocalIP()` in the service, and that's where the error happens.

Your problem should be in the following line:

```
let data = JSON.parse(appSettings.getString('retail_mobile'));
```

It's trying to parse something that is not parsable.

The problem here seems to be the mismatch. `appSettings.getString` is returning a string, therefore it cannot be parsed. By removing `JSON.parse` that should clear things out.

```
let data = appSettings.getString('retail_mobile')
```

If you want/need to use use JSON, which I would expect, you have to actually convert it to json and back somehow, e.g like below. It's not pretty, but should work.

```
findLocalIP() {
   let d = appSettings.getString('retail_mobile'); // add
   let d1 = JSON.stringify(d); // make it json
   let data = JSON.parse(d1); // now parse it
   if (data === null) {     
    console.log("No entry found in local storage...");
    return null;
   }
```

Just to set an example with string/json:

`retail_mobile = "{ something: "something" }"` 
This might look like JSON, but it is not, it's a string.

If you try `console.log(JSON.parse(retail_mobile))` it will throw you that error that you have.

BEFORE parsing you actually have to `JSON.stringify` it, so the following commands in this order would not produce an error:

```
retail_mobile = "{ something: "something" }"
let data = JSON.stringify(retail_mobile); 
console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```

And as a comment to you for referring that the errors point to .js-files. At runtime TS is compiled as JS, so it doesn't know or care about TS-files, therefore errors point to JS-files.

Comment: thanks for taking a look.  I added the following at the top of the getLocalIP function:   console.log(JSON.parse(appSettings.getString('retail_mobile')));
I don't se anything being logged to the windows command prompt?  This worked fine in the web app so it must be something Application-settings specific? All I did to the service was replace localService with appSettings and replace getItem with getString to try get it to work with Nativescript...

Comment: You are checking for null in your service-method, so shouldn't `appSettings.getString('retail_mobile‌​'))` return `null` in case there is not a ip set, right? If it's not logging anything, there is some problem there.

Comment: let data = appSettings.getString('retail_mobile‌'))  does return a null if data is null (just below that statement there's an if statement that checks?  Could it be that the error happens before the console.log is reached?

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation.  I can now log the value that's stored there.  it's undefined so shouldn't that be null?  i'm still getting the same error regardless of first getting the value then stringifying it and then parsing it...

Comment: When you retrieve the findIp for the first time, it will be undefined, unless you have actually explicitly set the value to null somewhere before trying to retrieve it.

Comment: So i'm guessing the invalid token U in JSon is the U in undefined?  So Undefined isn't the same as null?  would undefined be a string?  My goal is to check for a set IP every time the app starts and if it's not set navigate to a page where it can be set.

Comment: Yes, that would exactly be the case, the "u" stands for undefined in your error. undefined is not a string, but means that the value have not been defined in any way. Null  is actually when have DEFINED the value to be null :) You can just change the code to `if (data === undefined) {     
    console.log("No entry found in local storage...");` Works just as fine :)

Comment: Perhaps you should add ther OR operator as well, if you do assign the ip to be null sometimes, so `if (data === undefined || null)....`

Comment: Thanks again @AJT_82 for all your patience/effort.  i've never seen anyone on here that went to so much effort to help/explain whats going on...  It's working perfectly now!:)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!! :)